# Ошибка в методе GET

Tags: php

У меня есть таблица startpoke , мне нужно в столбик name_poke занести имя покемона, в шаблоне регистрации это выглядит так :

```
<input name='startpoke' type='radio' value='Bulbasaur' class='checkbox' >
```

А со стороны сервера так :

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO startpoke SET name_poke='.$_GET['startpoke']);
```

подскажите, в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO startpoke (name_poke) VALUES ("'.$_GET['startpoke'].'")');
```

Comment: старайтесь хоть попытаться самостоятельно решить проблему..
для этого нужно лишь открыть google.com и в поисковой строке набрать mysql insert И будет вам счастье )

Comment: ыыы)))))))

Comment: Я кажется скоро начну привышать полномочия и загоню кое-кого в минус)

@draev, а ваш вариант нерабочий) Сами догадаетесь?

Comment: а кого ?=)

Comment: @Sh4dow я с вами )
По поводу запроса, просто исправил сам sql. Передавать напрямую в б.д. данные из гета не есть гуд.. знаем )

Comment: А это еще и синтаксически неверно будет =) Блин, кавычки запилите уже в ответ, там текстовые данные)

Comment: исправлено, спасиб )

Answer (score 2):

ОМГ)

```
if(isset($_GET['startpoke']))
$startpoke = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['startpoke']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO startpoke (name_poke) VALUES ('$startpoke')");
```

Упс, меня опередили

Answer (score 2):

Уважаемые а где же защита? SQL Инъекции ни кто не отменял )

`mysql_real_escape_string();`

Comment: Совсем забыл) Спасибо

Comment: сознательно не написал.. исправил лишь sql запрос..